# json_decode no funciona con request de IBM Watson

Tags: php, json

estoy intentando hacer un pequeño archivo php que reciba un pedido hecho a través de un bot hecho con una skill de IBM Watson. Configuré el webhook de Watson para que llamase a mi script de php pero no consigo decodificar el json que me manda.

```
<?php
    $json_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $post = json_decode($json_post);
    if($post === NULL) {
        // Datos incorrectos, no se pudo decodificar
        die('Error obteniendo datos');
    }

    $file = fopen("pedidos.txt", "w");
    fwrite($file, $post);
    fclose($file);

    // Los datos son correctos
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json_post;
?>
```

para probar intenté meter la info en un archivo pero siempre me lo encuentro vacío. si quito la linea donde declaro $post y al fichero escribo $json_post obtengo esto `{"info":"14920","masa":"fina","time":"21:53:02","ingredientes":"jamón y queso"}` ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

Tu lógica aquí es incorrecta:

```
$post = json_decode($json_post) == NULL ? json_last_error() : $post;
```

Porque si falla `json_decode()` asignas el error al tratar de decodificar, si no falla, asignas `$post`, que es una variable no definida.

```
<?php
$json_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($json_post);
if($post === NULL) {
    // Datos incorrectos, no se pudo decodificar
    die('Error obteniendo datos');
}
// Los datos son correctos
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_post;
```

**Actualización:**

En este punto `$post` es un arreglo y no puedes guardarlo directamente en un archivo, de hecho, solo te sirve para comprobar que el `JSON` recibido es válido. `$json_post` es una cadena y sí puedes guardarla:

```
<?php
$json_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($json_post);
if($post === NULL) {
    // Datos incorrectos, no se pudo decodificar
    die('Error obteniendo datos');
}
// Los datos son correctos, guardar archivo
$file = fopen("pedidos.txt", "w");
// Guardar la cadena, no el arreglo
fwrite($file, $json_post);
fclose($file);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_post;
```

Comment: Llevas razón, había fallado en esa parte. Lo arreglé y me crea un archivo (por lo que $post no es NULL) pero el fichero sigue estando vacío. ¿Sabes qué puede ser?